# "Error: connect EACCES" при установке модуля express с помощью npm

Tags: node.js

Не получается установить модуль express, выдаёт ошибку:

[image: img]

Comment: > Please try running this .....
У вас прав не хватает. Не знаю как это под виндой сделать, но вам надо выполнить команду от имени администратора

Answer (score 3):

[@oneperson](/users/19267/oneperson), [смените директорию](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) на вашу рабочую директорию. в system32 не надо ничего ставить ни под юзером, ни под администратором.